# Article is wider than parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When my screen browser window is between 992px-1199px my article elements are wider than their parent div's (.wrapper). So at this screen width the panels overlap and look wrong.

At all other screen widths my code displays exactly how it should.

How can I make these .wrapper divs at least as wide as their children article element all the time?

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="datalist">
<div class="row">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("articles.json", function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            jQuery('<div/>', {
                id: 'div'+i,
                class: 'wrapper col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12',
            }).appendTo('.row')
            jQuery('<article/>', {
                id: 'article'+i,
                title: field.title,
                style: 'background-image: url('+field.thumbnail.url+');',
                height: field.thumbnail.height,
                width: field.thumbnail.width,
                class: 'panel panel-default',
            }).appendTo('#div'+i)

            if(field.type === "video"){
                jQuery('<img/>', {
                    src: '/img/youtubeIcon.png',
                    class: 'youtubeIcon'
                }).appendTo('#article'+i)

                jQuery('<button/>', {
                    id: 'playBtn'+i,
                    class: 'playBtn'
                }).appendTo('#article'+i)

                jQuery('<img/>', {
                    src: '/img/playIcon.png'
                }).appendTo('#playBtn'+i)
            }

            jQuery('<div/>', {
                class: 'panel-heading '+field.type,
                id: 'panelHeading'+i,
                title: field.title,
            }).appendTo('#article'+i)

            jQuery('<p/>', {
                text: field.title,
                class: 'panel-title'
            }).appendTo('#panelHeading'+i)

            var updated = '',
            now = Date.now(),
            secondsSince = ((now - field.updated)/1000),
            years = Math.floor(secondsSince / 31536000),
            days = Math.floor((secondsSince % 31536000) / 86400),
            months = days/30,
            hours = Math.floor(((secondsSince % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600),
            minutes = Math.floor((((secondsSince % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) /60)

            if (years > 1){
                updated = years + ' years ago'
            }
            else if (years > 0) {
                updated = years + ' year ago'
            } else if (months > 1){
                updated = months + ' months ago'
            } else if (months > 0){
                updated = months + ' month ago'
            } else if (day > 1){
                updated = days + ' days ago'
            } else if (day > 0){
                updated = days + ' day ago'
            } else if (hours > 1) {
                updated = hours + ' hours ago'
            } else if (hours > 0) {
                updated = hours + ' hour ago'
            }   else if (minutes > 1) {
                updated = minutes + ' minutes ago'
            } else {
                updated = 'A minute ago'
            }

            jQuery('<p/>', {
                text: updated,
                class: 'updated'
            }).appendTo('#panelHeading'+i)              
        })
    })
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
article {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.container{
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.youtubeIcon {
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 2px;
}

.playBtn {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.playBtn img{
    width: 50px;
    opacity: 0.85;

}
.wrapper{
    padding: 0;
}
.panel-default{
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.panel-heading {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0.5%;
    right: 0.5%;
    opacity: 0.75;
    padding: 1px 7px 2px 6px;
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    article:first-child .panel-heading {
        left: 0.25%;
        right: 0.25%;
    }
}
.panel-default>.panel-heading{
    background-color: #808080;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: none;
}
.panel-heading p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    paddig: 0;
    margin 0;
}
.panel-heading p:first-child{
    display: inline;
}
.panel-heading p:last-child{
    font-size: 8px; 
    padding-top: 2px;
    float: right;
}
.updated{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: `article:first-child .panel-heading { left: 0.25%; right: 0.25%; }` what is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Give your wrappers responsive widths, say width:100% (or whatever), and have the children inherit this.

Comment: Setting: 
   .wrapper{ 
     width: 100%;
   } 

does not work. it just makes each panel take up the whole width of the screen. basically displays them as if they were set to block.